# Ошибка разворота объекта

Tags: unity3d

Объект в данном случае это кот должен наводиться на мышь, он это делает но при повороте персонажа он тоже поворачивается из-за чего он начинает наводиться не правильно и смотрит не той стороной, пытаюсь починить 2 час. Не понимаю что не так, помогите пожалуйста.
На первом фото персонаж смотрит вправо и всё нормально, но на втором персонаж смотрит влево, а кот смотрит в противоположную сторону от курсора

это контроллер персонажа:

```
public class player_conroler : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    private Vector2 moveVelocity;

    public Animator hz;
    // задрало кароч
   

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

  

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;


        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);





    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
       

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0 & Input.GetAxis("Vertical") == 0)
        {
            hz.SetBool("IsRuning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            hz.SetBool("IsRuning", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == -1)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, -1);
            print("");
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 1)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

это код которым можно включить кота и вращать его:

```
    public class rotateinmouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float ofset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 diference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotateZ = Mathf.Atan2(diference.y, diference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotateZ + ofset);
        
        Vector3 localScale = Vector3.one;
        
        if (rotateZ > 90 || rotateZ < -90)
        {
            localScale.y = -1f;
          

        }
        else
        {
            localScale.y = +1f;
            

        }
        transform.localScale = localScale;


        }


    }
```

[image: это он смотрит вправо, всё нормально кот наводится правильно]

[image: это не правильно он смотрит не той стороной]

[image: вот полная иерархия объектов если надо]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в том, что скрипт `player_conroler` висит на объекте NormPlayer или player, а как следствие он делает отражение(которое через `transform.localScale`) всему объекту, включая и кота тоже. Поэтому когда вы двигаетесь влево, управление котом становится зеркальным. Как это решить:

1. Спрайт с телом(котором мы и хотим отразить в ту или другую сторону) выносите в отдельный объект. Возможно аниматор тоже надо перенести вместе со спрайтом.
2. В скрипте `player_conroler` добавляете переменную

   ```
   public Transform body
   ```
3. Код для отражения скрипте `player_conroler` меняете следующим образом

   ```
   if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == -1)
   {
       body.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, -1);
       print("");
   }
   else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 1)
   {
       body.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
   }
   ```

Базово идея в том, что отражать вы будете отдельный спрайт(читайте `GameObject` со `SpriteRenderer` на нем), а не всего плеера(что как раз и ломает вам логику с котом).